# How to listen for clipboard events in TideSDK?

Tags: tidesdk, tidekit

I want to listen for clipboard events (when something is copied), and then grab a copy for processing.

I can't seem to find an event for this within TideSDK. Even if I could, would this be triggered if the app isn't in focus?